# How can I use non-http TCP protocol on port 80 for 3G

Tags: networking, mobile, tcp, android-networking

I want to run a custom TCP protocol over a 3G connection for a game.  I decided to use port 80 because hey, it's open.  I'm aware that some paranoid ISPs will have stateful / application level firewalls that will reject TCP traffic based on some rules about non-http traffic or something.

How can I avoid firewall filtering on port 80?  I know its probably not possible in all cases.

Is there some minimal fake headers I can use in my data stream to satisfy such a gateway?